# Не запускается приложение Android

Tags: java, android

Ребят, помогите пожалуйста. 
При запуске, написанного приложения, выскакивает уведомление, что в работе приложения произошел сбой.

**Лог:**

```
09/29 16:20:23: Launching 'app' on Unknown Device.
$ adb shell am start -n "com.example.flagslist/com.example.flagslist.MainActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Waiting for process to come online...
Connected to process 22334 on device 'asus-asus_z017da-H1AZCY02T325LGM'.
Capturing and displaying logcat messages from application. This behavior can be disabled in the "Logcat output" section of the "Debugger" settings page.
V/Monotype: SetAppTypeFace- try to flip, app = com.example.flagslist
V/Monotype: Typeface getFontPathFlipFont - systemFont = default#default
I/zygote64: Do partial code cache collection, code=30KB, data=21KB
After code cache collection, code=30KB, data=21KB
Increasing code cache capacity to 128KB
V/Monotype: SetAppTypeFace- try to flip, app = com.example.flagslist
V/Monotype: Typeface getFontPathFlipFont - systemFont = default#default
I/zygote64: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<androidx.core.view.ViewCompat$OnUnhandledKeyEventListenerWrapper>: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroid/view/View$OnUnhandledKeyEventListener;
at void androidx.core.view.ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(android.view.View, androidx.core.view.OnApplyWindowInsetsListener) (ViewCompat.java:2203)
at android.view.ViewGroup androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.createSubDecor() (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:637)
at void androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.ensureSubDecor() (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:518)
at void androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(int) (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:466)
at void androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(int) (AppCompatActivity.java:140)
at void com.example.flagslist.MainActivity.onCreate(android.os.Bundle) (MainActivity.java:37)
at void android.app.Activity.performCreate(android.os.Bundle) (Activity.java:7016)
at void android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(android.app.Activity, android.os.Bundle) (Instrumentation.java:1214)
at android.app.Activity android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent) (ActivityThread.java:2780)
at void android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent, java.lang.String) (ActivityThread.java:2902)
at void android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(android.app.ActivityThread, android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent, java.lang.String) (ActivityThread.java:-1)
at void android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(android.os.Message) (ActivityThread.java:1603)
at void android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(android.os.Message) (Handler.java:105)
at void android.os.Looper.loop() (Looper.java:169)
at void android.app.ActivityThread.main(java.lang.String[]) (ActivityThread.java:6578)
at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object[]) (Method.java:-2)
at void com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() (Zygote.java:240)
at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(java.lang.String[]) (ZygoteInit.java:767)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.view.View$OnUnhandledKeyEventListener" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.flagslist-A7otiNFtGQB4qTK4wbeksA==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.flagslist-A7otiNFtGQB4qTK4wbeksA==/lib/arm64, /system/lib64, /system/vendor/lib64]]
at java.lang.Class dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(java.lang.String) (BaseDexClassLoader.java:93)
at java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(java.lang.String, boolean) (ClassLoader.java:379)
at java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(java.lang.String) (ClassLoader.java:312)
at void androidx.core.view.ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(android.view.View, androidx.core.view.OnApplyWindowInsetsListener) (ViewCompat.java:2203)
at android.view.ViewGroup androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.createSubDecor() (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:637)
at void androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.ensureSubDecor() (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:518)
at void androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(int) (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:466)
I/zygote64: at void androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(int) (AppCompatActivity.java:140)
at void com.example.flagslist.MainActivity.onCreate(android.os.Bundle) (MainActivity.java:37)
at void android.app.Activity.performCreate(android.os.Bundle) (Activity.java:7016)
at void android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(android.app.Activity, android.os.Bundle) (Instrumentation.java:1214)
at android.app.Activity android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent) (ActivityThread.java:2780)
at void android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent, java.lang.String) (ActivityThread.java:2902)
at void android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(android.app.ActivityThread, android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent, java.lang.String) (ActivityThread.java:-1)
at void android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(android.os.Message) (ActivityThread.java:1603)
at void android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(android.os.Message) (Handler.java:105)
at void android.os.Looper.loop() (Looper.java:169)
at void android.app.ActivityThread.main(java.lang.String[]) (ActivityThread.java:6578)
at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object[]) (Method.java:-2)
at void com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() (Zygote.java:240)
at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(java.lang.String[]) (ZygoteInit.java:767)
Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<androidx.core.view.ViewCompat$OnUnhandledKeyEventListenerWrapper>: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroid/view/View$OnUnhandledKeyEventListener;
I/zygote64: at void androidx.core.view.ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(android.view.View, androidx.core.view.OnApplyWindowInsetsListener) (ViewCompat.java:2203)
at android.view.ViewGroup androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.createSubDecor() (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:637)
at void androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.ensureSubDecor() (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:518)
at void androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(int) (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:466)
at void androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(int) (AppCompatActivity.java:140)
at void com.example.flagslist.MainActivity.onCreate(android.os.Bundle) (MainActivity.java:37)
at void android.app.Activity.performCreate(android.os.Bundle) (Activity.java:7016)
at void android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(android.app.Activity, android.os.Bundle) (Instrumentation.java:1214)
at android.app.Activity android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent) (ActivityThread.java:2780)
at void android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent, java.lang.String) (ActivityThread.java:2902)
at void android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(android.app.ActivityThread, android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent, java.lang.String) (ActivityThread.java:-1)
at void android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(android.os.Message) (ActivityThread.java:1603)
at void android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(android.os.Message) (Handler.java:105)
at void android.os.Looper.loop() (Looper.java:169)
at void android.app.ActivityThread.main(java.lang.String[]) (ActivityThread.java:6578)
at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object[]) (Method.java:-2)
at void com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() (Zygote.java:240)
at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(java.lang.String[]) (ZygoteInit.java:767)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.view.View$OnUnhandledKeyEventListener" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.flagslist-A7otiNFtGQB4qTK4wbeksA==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.flagslist-A7otiNFtGQB4qTK4wbeksA==/lib/arm64, /system/lib64, /system/vendor/lib64]]
at java.lang.Class dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(java.lang.String) (BaseDexClassLoader.java:93)
at java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(java.lang.String, boolean) (ClassLoader.java:379)
at java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(java.lang.String) (ClassLoader.java:312)
at void androidx.core.view.ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(android.view.View, androidx.core.view.OnApplyWindowInsetsListener) (ViewCompat.java:2203)
at android.view.ViewGroup androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.createSubDecor() (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:637)
at void androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.ensureSubDecor() (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:518)
at void androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(int) (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:466)
at void androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(int) (AppCompatActivity.java:140)
at void com.example.flagslist.MainActivity.onCreate(android.os.Bundle) (MainActivity.java:37)
at void android.app.Activity.performCreate(android.os.Bundle) (Activity.java:7016)
at void android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(android.app.Activity, android.os.Bundle) (Instrumentation.java:1214)
at android.app.Activity android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent) (ActivityThread.java:2780)
at void android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent, java.lang.String) (ActivityThread.java:2902)
at void android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(android.app.ActivityThread, android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent, java.lang.String) (ActivityThread.java:-1)
at void android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(android.os.Message) (ActivityThread.java:1603)
at void android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(android.os.Message) (Handler.java:105)
at void android.os.Looper.loop() (Looper.java:169)
at void android.app.ActivityThread.main(java.lang.String[]) (ActivityThread.java:6578)
at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object[]) (Method.java:-2)
at void com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() (Zygote.java:240)
at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(java.lang.String[]) (ZygoteInit.java:767)
Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<androidx.core.view.ViewCompat$OnUnhandledKeyEventListenerWrapper>: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroid/view/View$OnUnhandledKeyEventListener;
at void androidx.core.view.ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(android.view.View, androidx.core.view.OnApplyWindowInsetsListener) (ViewCompat.java:2203)
at android.view.ViewGroup androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.createSubDecor() (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:637)
at void androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.ensureSubDecor() (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:518)
at void androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(int) (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:466)
at void androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(int) (AppCompatActivity.java:140)
at void com.example.flagslist.MainActivity.onCreate(android.os.Bundle) (MainActivity.java:37)
at void android.app.Activity.performCreate(android.os.Bundle) (Activity.java:7016)
at void android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(android.app.Activity, android.os.Bundle) (Instrumentation.java:1214)
at android.app.Activity android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent) (ActivityThread.java:2780)
at void android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent, java.lang.String) (ActivityThread.java:2902)
at void android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(android.app.ActivityThread, android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent, java.lang.String) (ActivityThread.java:-1)
at void android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(android.os.Message) (ActivityThread.java:1603)
at void android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(android.os.Message) (Handler.java:105)
I/zygote64: at void android.os.Looper.loop() (Looper.java:169)
at void android.app.ActivityThread.main(java.lang.String[]) (ActivityThread.java:6578)
at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object[]) (Method.java:-2)
at void com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() (Zygote.java:240)
at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(java.lang.String[]) (ZygoteInit.java:767)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.view.View$OnUnhandledKeyEventListener" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.flagslist-A7otiNFtGQB4qTK4wbeksA==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.flagslist-A7otiNFtGQB4qTK4wbeksA==/lib/arm64, /system/lib64, /system/vendor/lib64]]
at java.lang.Class dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(java.lang.String) (BaseDexClassLoader.java:93)
at java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(java.lang.String, boolean) (ClassLoader.java:379)
at java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(java.lang.String) (ClassLoader.java:312)
at void androidx.core.view.ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(android.view.View, androidx.core.view.OnApplyWindowInsetsListener) (ViewCompat.java:2203)
at android.view.ViewGroup androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.createSubDecor() (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:637)
at void androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.ensureSubDecor() (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:518)
at void androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(int) (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:466)
at void androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(int) (AppCompatActivity.java:140)
at void com.example.flagslist.MainActivity.onCreate(android.os.Bundle) (MainActivity.java:37)
at void android.app.Activity.performCreate(android.os.Bundle) (Activity.java:7016)
at void android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(android.app.Activity, android.os.Bundle) (Instrumentation.java:1214)
at android.app.Activity android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent) (ActivityThread.java:2780)
at void android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent, java.lang.String) (ActivityThread.java:2902)
at void android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(android.app.ActivityThread, android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent, java.lang.String) (ActivityThread.java:-1)
at void android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(android.os.Message) (ActivityThread.java:1603)
at void android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(android.os.Message) (Handler.java:105)
at void android.os.Looper.loop() (Looper.java:169)
at void android.app.ActivityThread.main(java.lang.String[]) (ActivityThread.java:6578)
at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object[]) (Method.java:-2)
at void com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() (Zygote.java:240)
at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(java.lang.String[]) (ZygoteInit.java:767)
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.flagslist, PID: 22334
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.flagslist/com.example.flagslist.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class RealativeLayout
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2827)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2902)
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1603)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:169)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6578)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class RealativeLayout
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class RealativeLayout
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.view.RealativeLayout" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.flagslist-A7otiNFtGQB4qTK4wbeksA==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.flagslist-A7otiNFtGQB4qTK4wbeksA==/lib/arm64, /system/lib64, /system/vendor/lib64]]
at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:93)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:606)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:703)
at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:68)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:720)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:788)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:730)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:469)
at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
at com.example.flagslist.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:37)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7016)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1214)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2780)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2902)
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1603)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:169)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6578)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
Device asus-asus_z017da-H1AZCY02T325LGM disconnected, monitoring stopped.
```

MainActivity.java:

```
package com.example.flagslist;

import androidx.annotation.RequiresApi;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toolbar;

import java.util.function.ToLongBiFunction;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Toolbar mToolbar;
    ListView mListView;

    String[] countryNames = {"Canada", "China", "Germany", "Japan", "Kazakhstan", "Poland", "Russia", "Singapore", "United Kingdom of Great Britain", "USA"};
    int[] countryFlags = {R.drawable.canada_flag,
            R.drawable.china_flag,
            R.drawable.germany_flag,
            R.drawable.japan_flag,
            R.drawable.kazakhstan_flag,
            R.drawable.poland_flag,
            R.drawable.russian_flag,
            R.drawable.singapore_flag,
            R.drawable.uk_flag,
            R.drawable.usa_flag};

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mToolbar = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        mToolbar.setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.app_name));
        mListView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listview);
        MyAdapter myAdapter = new MyAdapter(MainActivity.this, countryNames, countryFlags);
        mListView.setAdapter(myAdapter);
        mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                Intent mIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, DetailActivity.class);
                mIntent.putExtra("countryName", countryNames[i]);
                mIntent.putExtra("countryFlag", countryFlags[i]);
                startActivity(mIntent);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RealativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</RealativeLayout>
```

myAdapter

```
public class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

String[] names;
int[] flags;
Context mContext;

public MyAdapter(@NonNull Context context, String[] countryNames, int[] countryFlags) {
    super(context, R.layout.listview_item);
    this.names = countryNames;
    this.flags = countryFlags;
    this.mContext = context;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return names.length;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder mViewHolder = new ViewHolder();
    if(convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.
                getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_item, parent, false);
        mViewHolder.mFlag = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        mViewHolder.mName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView);
        convertView.setTag(mViewHolder);
    }
    else{
        mViewHolder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
    }
        mViewHolder.mFlag.setImageResource(flags[position]);
        mViewHolder.mName.setText(names[position]);

    return convertView;
}

static class ViewHolder{
    ImageView mFlag;
    TextView mName;
}
```

}

Comment: На myAdapter жалуется. Кстати, тут его нет.

Comment: `Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class RealativeLayout` ругается на `activity_main.xml`

Comment: RealativeLayout очепятка, RelativeLayout поставь и не будет ругаться. И советую не месить android support с androidx

Comment: @ВладимирМалахов добавил код myAdapter